# How would I link these strings and integers

Tags: class, python-2.7

So When I run this code it gives me an error saying it cannot concatenate the str and int on line 7. The goal was to have the volume of the RectangularPrism be calculated for the given code with the obvious volume formula of length * width * height, as well as the surface area by finding the area of each side and multiply it by 2.

```
class RectangularPrism(object):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def volume(self):
        return "The volume is " + (self.length*self.width*self.height)
    def surfaceArea(self):
        return "The surface area is "+ (self.length * self.width * 2 + self.length * self.height * 2 + self.height * self.width * 2)



class cube(RectangularPrism):
    def __init__(self, baka):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def volume(self):
        return "The volume is "+ (self.length*self.width*self.height)
    def surfaceArea(self):
        return "The surface area is "+ (self.length * self.width * 2 + self.length * self.height * 2 + self.height * self.width * 2)


box1 = RectangularPrism(2, 3, 4)
print box1
print "Volume = " + str(box1.volume())
print "Suface Area = " + str(box1.surfaceArea())

print

box2 = Cube(2)
print box2
print "Volume = " + str(box2.volume())
print "Suface Area = " + str(box2.surfaceArea())
```

Comment: What do you think will be the type of the result of the expression `(self.length*self.width*self.height)`?

Comment: Well in all of that line of code 'return "The volume is "+ (self.length * self.width * self.height', I expected it to return the volume of given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried return `"The volume is %s" % (self.length*self.width*self.height)`, which will convert int to string

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't concatenate a string and an integer.  Change the integer into a string:

```
return "The volume is " + str(self.length*self.width*self.height)
```

You can also use string formatting:

```
return "The volume is {}".format(self.length*self.width*self.height)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to solve the issue. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it was useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment because of my reputation, the problem with your code is that (or so I think it is) you are trying to add two different types. A string and an integer. Try replacing the `+` with a `,`. However, do not take my word for what the problem is, I would wait for someone with a good knowledge of Python to explain it to you. If you just want the answer, then I think my solution would work.